# Solving an optimization problem with a linear objective and quadratic constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The title is general, but what I am specifically interested in, is how to solve the following problem:

$$\text{Maximize } c  $$
$$\text{Subject to:}$$
$$a+b+c<0$$
$$b^2-4ac<0$$
$$a,b \in \mathbb{R}, c \in \mathbb{Z}$$

I can solve it by first showing that $c$ cannot be positive or zero, and then showing that $c=-1$ has a solution. But this kind of solution is not satisfying to me, I want to just get the solution of $c = -1$ directly. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $b^2 - 4ac < 0$ means that the quadratic form
$$ f(x,y) = a x^2 + bxy + cy^2 $$
is definite, either positive definite or negative definite. Then
$$ f(1,1) = a + b + c < 0$$ 
means negative definite, since it is a value attained by the form.
Finally
$$ f(0,1) = c, $$
so $c < 0.$

Since they want $c$ integral, $ c \leq -1.$

Comment: You can make it even simpler by saying that $b^2-4ac<0$ implies that parabola $ax^2+bx+c$ is either always positive or always negative, and then $a+b+c<0$ implies that parabola is always negative. Since the only thing we know is that parabola is always negative, we can find a parabola which would pass through $-1$ when $x$ is zero, and so maximum $c$ is $-1$.